# How to cut a part of image in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I need to make the following image in Photoshop cs6

[image]:

What I did is made two circles, one with light green color the second with dark green color as:

[image] [image]

Then I covered light circle with the darker circle. After that I drew a quadrilateral with the Lasso tool. Then I selected the quadrilateral with Quick selection tool and deleted that portion of the darker circle. The problem is that the quick selection tool doesn't cut area with smooth boundaries. The sides of quadrilateral are pixelated. So,

Is there any way to cut custom shape from an image/layer in Photoshop with smooth boundaries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think I really understood the description. If you want to make a circle just like the one in your first example, you could do it this way.

1. Draw a circle with the `Ellipse tool`. Make sure it's a `Shape`.
2. <kbd>Cmd + C</kbd> ( Copy ) - Makes a copy of the `Path` you just made for the `Shape`
3. <kbd>Cmd + V</kbd> ( Paste ) - Duplicates the `Path`
4. <kbd>Cmd + T</kbd> ( Free transform ) - To quickly make the new `Path` smaller than the original. This is all happening within a single `Shape` layer.
5. From the tool options: `Subtract front shape` and `Merge shape components`.
6. At this point you got the first circle. Lower its opacity, to make it a bit faded ( ...or change its color ). Then you can duplicate it with <kbd>Cmd + J</kbd>. Make sure to give the new ellipse 100% opacity or different color, so you can differentiate between them.
7. Now you can use the `Pen` tool, to draw a triangle from the center of the circle. Make sure it's a `Shape`.
8. Merge this triangle `Shape` layer with the second ellipse `Shape` layer. Select them both and <kbd>Cmd + E</kbd>.

   - This is only possible in later versions of PS. I believe CS 6 and higher. In case you can't merge shapes like this, at step 7 make sure you got the second ellipse `Shape` layer selected and that `Pen` tool is set to `Path` instead of `Shape`. This way you can draw additional paths inside the ellipse `Shape` layer, making this merging step unnecessary.
   - I just wanted to show both techniques just in case. Making separate shape layers and merging them can be way easier though.
9. Then do the same thing as before. From the tool options: `Subtract front shape` and `Merge shape components`.

> In the gif below I have made guides to mark the center of the document. This is
>   so that I can easily draw the triangle from the center of the ellipse
>   object.
>
> Note that I'm also using <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>
>   modifiers, when using Free transform and when I'm drawing the circles.
>
> On windows, just replace <kbd>Cmd</kbd> with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and you
>   get the same result.

[image]

Comment: The second circle is not unzooming with respect to its center. When I unzoom with transformation its bottom left edge remains fixed.

Comment: @user it sounds like your transform origin is at the bottom left. In the options bar change the origin to the center.

Comment: Press `Alt` and `Shift` when you're drawing the circle and also when you're using Free transform.  `Alt` makes things happen from the center and `Shift` makes sure it's a perfect circle. You can release these modifier keys after you release the mouse button.

Comment: @CAI In the options bar origin is already selected. Even if I change it any other point like right bottom edge the unzomming always occurs with respect to bottom left edge. Although pressing `alt` works.

Comment: Setting the reference point as @CAI suggests works if you use the input fields in the tool options to scale the circle. When you manually scale it by dragging one of the corners, the reference point becomes the opposite point to the one you're dragging ( Unless you hold down Alt ).

Comment: @Joonas Did you join elipse1 and shape1 before selecting _subtract front shape_ in your last step?

Comment: Yes, at step 8 I use `Shift` to select both layers and then use the hotkey for `Merge`.  If hotkeys are not your thing, you can also right click one of the selected layers in the `Layers panel` and select `Merge shapes`.

Comment: The 9th step doesn't delete the triangle from the darker circle. Also why did we merge the darker circle and the triangle? What if didn't have the lighter circle and we wanted only to delete a triangle from one circle only?

Comment: So in Photoshop you got `Paths` and you got `Shapes`. `Shape` is basically a layer that contains `Paths`. If we forget that the lighter ellipse exists, for now... Before step 8, what you got is 2 `Shape` layers. The ellipse `Shape` layer and the triangle `Shape` layer. There is 1 `Path` in the ellipse `Shape` and 1 `Path` in the triangle `Shape`. For you to be able to subtract a `Shape` with a `Path`, the `Path` needs to be in within that `Shape` you want to subtract from. That's why the triangle `Shape` and ellipse `Shape` are merged into a single `Shape`.

Comment: No. All of that happens inside that one ellipse `Shape` layer. If you look at the gif, when I make the first circle, I only have 1 layer + Background layer, until I duplicate the circle into another layer to create the darker circle. Those are just 2 `Paths` inside one `Shape` layer.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment because it could be wrong. Now I am not able to work the 9th step. Also Instead of copying the first circle if I make a new circle then _subtract front layer_ doesn't work.

Comment: Yes. You would need to merge the two `Shape` layers in that case. Just like I'm doing in the gif after I draw the triangle.

Comment: Here is what is happening. If I make two different circles(layers), one bigger and other smaller. I superimpose the smaller upon the bigger one and then merge them. Both of them get the same color and none of the _path of operations_ like _subtract from the front_ work. On the other hand if I make a bigger circle then replace the check mark inside the _path operation_ from _new layer_ to _subtract from front_ then make another circle then the other circle automatically deletes the parts overlapping b/w the circles. 2nd is neither merged nor inside the 1st circle.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if I got the latter part of that, but I can explain what is happening in the first part. I wrote these instructions / made the gif with the assumption that they are followed exactly, so I don't have to write extra steps. See, when I make the triangle and merge it with the ellipse, the triangle `Path` stays selected, so when `Subtract` is chosen, it subtracts using that `Path`. In your case, you probably don't have the correct `path` selected, if any.

Comment: **In this scenario that you explained in the first half of the comment above:** After merging the two layers, make sure you got the smaller circle `Path` selected. Take `Path` tool and click once inside the smaller circle `Path`. This should make the anchor points visible. Then if you do `Subtract`, it will use that path to subtract.

Answer (score 1):

What if you create a mask? Instead of deleting that portion you just change the color to the lighter green.

Comment: I don't know about masks.

Answer (score 0):

The Lasso tool already makes a selection so you shouldn't need to use the Quick Selection tool as well.

With the Lasso tool active increase the **Feather** value and make sure **Anti-Aliasing** is checked (in the Options bar). That will give you the smooth edges you need.

To create a mask instead of destructively deleting pixels, just make your selection and hit the mask button at the bottom of the layers panel (with the layer you want to mask selected).

All of that being said, you should really be creating this with [shape layers](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/drawing-shapes.html) instead of directly drawing and deleting pixels.

Comment: Without _Quick Selection Tool_ I am unable to deleted the portion drawn with Lasso tool.

Comment: Also adding the mask makes the cut portion dark green and rest of the ring light green -- opposite to what I want to acheive.

Comment: The lasso tool makes a selection—thats all it does, so I'm not sure how the quick selection tool even works with that...

Comment: For the mask you just need to invert the mask. Select the masks thumbnail in the layers panel and hit `cmd`+`I`.

Comment: You should be working with shapes anyway, so forget selections and masks and do as [Joonas' answer shows](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/70444/52050).

Comment: With quick selection tool I click the quadrilateral area made with Lasso Tool then hitting delete deletes that area. Also I do not have `cmd` button on my keyboard. I want to know this method too so that I could delete parts of jpg images.

Comment: `cmd` on Mac == `ctrl` on Windows in most cases.

Comment: The Lasso tool makes a selection. The quick selection tool makes a selection. Im not sure how or why you would need to make a selection from a selection so I don't know whats going on there.

Comment: I don't know photoshop vocabulary. What I did is simply draw a quardilateral with Lasso tool over the dark green circle. Now pressing delete doesn't delete that quadrilateral's area. Now I pick _Quick selection tool_. With this tool I click inside the quadrilateral multiple times to spread the outline drawn with it. Then I press delete and the quadrilateral area gets deleted.

Comment: Sounds like you are drawing with the polygon tool, not the lasso tool, but I don't know. Photoshop help files will help with most of this.

Comment: Yes I am  using the polygon Lasso  tool. Then the Quick selection tool.